# xrandr: change saturation (less color, more black/white)

Tags: shell, colors, display, xrandr, monitors

I know how to change brightness and gamma with `xrandr`:

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --brightness 0.8 --gamma "0.90:0.85:0.80"
```

but how can I change saturation, ie decrease the amount of color and move on the spectrum closer to black/white ?

I need a way to change this on the command line, not on the hardware settings of my monitor.

I am using Debian 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most convenient way (as of 2022) is via a tool named [`vibrant-cli`](https://github.com/libvibrant/libvibrant) (which should work on any `X11` setup). The syntax is:

```
vibrant-cli OUTPUT [SATURATION]
```

```
Get or set saturation of output.

OUTPUT is the name of the X11 output. You can find this by running xrandr.
SATURATION is a floating point value between (including) 0.0 and (including) 4.0.

    0.0 or 0 means monochrome
    1.0 or 1 is normal color saturation (100%)
    if empty the saturation will not be changed
```

e.g. to reduce saturation to 30% on my laptop I'd run

```
vibrant-cli eDP-1 0.3
```

```
libvibrant version 1.0.2
Saturation of eDP-1 is 0.300000
```

`libvibrant` identifies your graphics chipset and attempts to change the saturation via the known methods supported by the driver for that particular GPU. If your hardware/drivers don't support changing color vibrance, you'll get an error.
Note that Color Management for DRM (Direct Rendering Manager) layer is [rather recent](https://www.spinics.net/lists/dri-devel/msg90171.html):

```
Color Manager framework defines a color correction property for color space
transformation and Gamut mapping.  
This property is called CTM (Color Transformation Matrix).

This patch adds a new structure in DRM layer for CTM. This structure can be used
by all user space agents to configure CTM coefficients for color correction.
```

So, in order to determine whether your platform supports color management via open-source drivers<sup>1</sup> (`i915` and `amdgpu`) you would run `xrandr --properties`. If there is no mention of `CTM` or if it says `CTM: 0` then your setup doesn't support changing saturation via `CTM` (maybe via other methods, see the note at the bottom of the post concerning nVidia).
If you have a line like `CTM:  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1` e.g. for `eDP-1` output:

```
..................
eDP-1 connected primary.....
..................
link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
        0 1 
CONNECTOR_ID: 78 
        supported: 78
```

then your setup supports color management i.e. the property `C`olor `T`ransform `M`atrix can be set... This is still a job of `vibrant-cli` unless, of course, you want to do the math yourself... for instance, to set saturation to `0` (grayscale) the command is

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --set CTM '1431655765,0,1431655765,0,1431655765,0,1431655765,0,1431655765,0,1431655765,0,1431655765,0,1431655765,0,1431655765,0'
```

---

<sup>1: I only have access to those two platforms (and I have not tried the AMD proprietary driver - no idea if it supports `CTM`). For the `nVidia` GPUs, apparently there's a property called `digital vibrance` that can be set (when using the nVidia driver) via [nVidia control panel](https://www.nvidia.com/content/Control-Panel-Help/vLatest/en-us/mergedProjects/nvdsp/To_use_Digital_Vibrance_to_make_your_desktop_colors_richer.htm) or in terminal running e.g. `nvidia-settings -a [gpu:0]/DigitalVibrance[DFP-1]=235` (consult the manual for proper syntax). I don't know if `nouveau` supports the same property or not...</sup>

Comment: thank you. I have compiled `vibrant-cli`, but when I run it, I get: `Cannot find output DisplayPort-0 in the list of supported outputs, it either does not exist or is not supported`

Comment: my GPU is: `Radeon_Pro_WX_5100`. And I have pasted xrandr output here: https://ctxt.io/2/AAAQnxiVFQ

Comment: I am using open source driver (in linux kernel)

Comment: @400theCat - support for CTM was added to the xf86 video driver [not long ago](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/amd-gfx/2018-May/022007.html) if you read the discussion it says _"If kernel driver does not support color management, the properties will remain disabled."_ so if your kernel doesn't support it I'm afraid there's not much you can do. Try adding `amdgpu.dc=1` to your boot parameters and see if that changes anything. Other than that you could try a very up-to-date linux LIVEUSB (e.g. Manjaro) and see if things change when using the most recent kernel/xorg drivers.

Comment: thank you for your investigation. Does it mean, with current kernel, it will not work using `vibrant`, while some other tool might work? Or will it not work in principle, because GPU driver does not support this operation?

Comment: @400theCat - `libvibrant` is pretty good at detecting the gpu and whether that or driver supports color adjustment. I am pretty sure in your case it's a matter of driver. Unfortunately I don't have access to any workstation with that particular hardware. As I said, the best thing you could do is to download a LIVEUSB image like e.g. Archbang (which is small size) or any other distro that has recent kernel and drivers. Boot from USB and run `xrandr --props` ... if you see a line like `CTM:  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0`  then yes, your card is supported in newer versions of kernel/drivers.

Comment: Hey, this is very cool! Where can I find documentation on the calculation of the Color Transformation Matrix?

Comment: @aizquier I'd start by looking into `libvibrant` source code and the kernel [`drm`  code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/gpu/drm/drm_color_mgmt.c)

Comment: @aizquier I remember reading a more detailed explanation somewhere back then but right now all I can find  [is this](https://www.mail-archive.com/linux-kernel@vger.kernel.org/msg1322771.html)...